# Where can I setup a persistent directory on my Android phone with a symlink-compatible filesystem?

Tags: file-system

I want to setup a directory on an Android phone which provides a similar experience to a traditional Linux command line.

Normally I would work from my home directory but `HOME` in this case resolves `/sdcard` and is mounted as sdcardfs which is an emulated filesystem that does not support traditional features such as symbolic links:

> Now `/sdcard` is not a real but emulated storage which represents a
>   FAT/vFAT/FAT32 filesystem (for backward compatibility and permission
>   management) which [doesn't support symlinks](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218944/218526) (and other things including
>   *NIX permissions and `ioctls` like `FS_IOC_FIEMAP`). So the Option 1 and 3 of yours won't work whether you create symlink directly on emulated
>   storage or try to emulate the symlink already created on ext4.

Source: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203989

If I can't use `/sdcard` as a traditional filesystem then where else can I go for safe and persistent storage where I can use *NIX features that I am used to such as symbolic links, hard links, ioctls, ACLs, etc.?

Please note that I am not looking for alternatives for these features such as using `mount` as a replacement for links. The issue I have is that I don't know what is considered safe and persistent for storage on this device.

As an example of the problem I am facing, I tried creating a directory in `/mnt`, which provided the necessary features, but this directory was not persistent after the device was rebooted.

My phone is rooted and I am using aftermarket firmware.

Comment: Every app can create symlinks in its private storage (which is `ext4` or `f2fs`) but private storage isn't accessible to other apps. And actually that's why Android uses an emulated permission-less filesystem. On normal *NIX systems storage isn't shared among multiple users, every UID owns its unique home directory. // On rooted phones you can share some directory in `/data` with root-enabled apps. A subdirectory in `/data/local/tmp/` can also be shared by apps but SELinux policy on mostly devices doesn't allow this. On Android 10+ apps have even restricted filesystem access in shared storage.

Comment: for rooted devices `/data/media/0` is another way to access `/sdcard` (with wanted file system type)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Didn't Google postpone their new restrictions to 11+ following developers' backlash?

Comment: @alecxs It should be noted that every file under `/data/media/0` needs to be owned by a specific user and group, or issues might arise in `/sdcard` and similar mount points.

Comment: @Grimoire doesn't matter, symlink only work from /data/media/0 which requires root access. btw uid:gid is all the same (1023:1023) and android does chown this automatically on boot since oreo

Comment: @alecxs `/data/media/0` exists but is empty on my device (accessed as root). It is running Android 7.1.2.

Comment: disable namespace separation (set namespaces to global)