# Symlink from /sdcard to /sdcard

Tags: adb, internal-storage, screenshots

I am trying to have Google Markup output its image somewhere other than its default location. I have used different ROMs and versions of those ROMs, and each combination I tried has Google Markup's output location change. Google Markup doesn't look like it has any settings to change its behavior, so I tried to adapt its output to my desired location. The default output on my current setup is at `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.google.android.markup/Markups/`, but I would like to have it at `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/`. I tried the following from Windows ADB:

```
RMX1921:/ $ su
RMX1921:/ # ln -s /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.google.android.markup/Markups /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/
ln: cannot create symbolic link from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.google.android.markup/Markup' to '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots//Markup': Operation not permitted
RMX1921:/ #
```

I'm using a Realme XT with DerpFest 10 build 2020-03-29 (Android 10r31) rooted with Magisk v20.4 if it matters. Is there any way I can automatically redirect Google Markup's output to a different location?

Additional things I would like to do:

- Markup leaves the original file behind on this system (also one of the inconsistent behaviors of Markup on different ROMs). I would like to get the file name of the original file, and use it to rename the file Markup generates. The format is: `Screenshot_YYYYMMDD-hh-mm-ss.png`.
- After moving the file, delete the original file, which is at `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/`.

I'm thinking of a script that constantly runs in the background, doesn't have to be instant, maybe it triggers and checks and processes everything once every 5 seconds. But I feel like I might be overcomplicating a lot of things. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/` is a standard location where apps can store data without having Storage permission: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526. // Symlinks are not supported in emulated storage: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218944/218526. // You can use some automation app to achieve what you want. Or with root access use bind mount, may be.

Comment: If you are looking for newly created file Android supports the inotify events where you can wait for certain file-system events. Therefore a scripted solution does not have to poll for file-changes. Using inotify-tols for Android you simply have to wait for the matching file-system event.

Comment: I am an idiot. I forgot about automation apps. I now have an excuse to learn how to use those. Thanks a lot! Probably saves me the headache of having to do it all manually xD