# How to "adb push" files from linux to android without the non-permissive symlinks

Tags: adb, android-sdk

I want to push over 120K small files including symlinks using "adb" but without those links if they fail in "remote symlink failed: Permission denied" to Android device.

Comment: Copying a large number of files from/to the device you better tar the files and extract them after transferring them. Using `adb exec-in` you can pipe the tar file to the device and directly extract them without ever saving the tar file.

Comment: that will defeat the purpose of fast copying, packaging and extracting is not the right approach to this problem.

Comment: Irrespective of what method you use to transfer files, symlinks aren't supported in Android's shared storage: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218944/218526

Comment: thats why i need to skip those :)

Comment: You want to skip symlinks? I couldn't get that point from your question. `adb push` provides no filtering options based on file type. You need to use some other method, possibly combined with `adb push` e.g. `find -type`. But pushing individual files would largely reduce the transfer rate. Better use some other file transfer method.